# How to Solve Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I'm getting this error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /SideBar/Save/0

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmbH6.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCYTp.png)

[image: Controller 2]

[image]

I using a SideBarController and my View (Save) have place properly. Why is the resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable?

I don't understand how to solve it....

TQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you pass 0 as a URL but you pass some available record id that is the issue:

You need to change here:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { UserId=item.UserId})
```

when you click on edit link then for example:

```
SideBar/Save/12
```

Click on Edit Button and check if the id is shown then you should be going edit record

if above criteria did not work then here come:

if give again error nullable type then change again in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult Save(int? id)
{

}
```

it works.

Comment: @JHOng Every project you have facing this problem?

Comment: @JHOng If you run multiple projects same time or multiple time may be error occur check I m pretty sure problem with IIS configuration check it

Comment: u c my controller 2 image My HomeController have File HomeController , if i create new one then don't have file inside my controller

Comment: i dont know Why like this

Comment: @JHOng sry I don't understand the question but I m definitely sure what is an error you need to change  here ```UserId=item.UserId``` and I m sure it is workable

Comment: 1st i created a empty Controller... then im click on the controller got PUBLIC ACTIONRESULT INDEX () ... after that i double click index for add new view BUT don't show the add view

Comment: U c the Image 4 i insert that is diffrence..... No add View inside

Comment: @JHOng which error you have shown I solved error in my above answer this is your new question I m very glad if you ask a new question for your new problem